# notation question regarding maps of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

If you have two topological spaces $(X,\mathscr{T_1})$ and $(Y,\mathscr{T_2})$. I have seen that this is usually simplified to $X$ and $Y$. So when we have a function  $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$, does this mean f maps open sets from the topology on $X$ to the topology on $Y$ or elements from the set X to the set Y?

I believe it is the latter.

Comment: It is the latter. Topological spaces or not, $f: X \to Y$ always maps elements of $X$ to elements of $Y$.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy is of course correct. However, when they write somewhere that $f : X\to Y$ is supposed to be continuous, they mean that with respect to the given (and omitted) topologies.